# Android doesn't auto kill/free memory when my app asks for more memory

Tags: android, memory

I have an android app that uses alot of memory doing pixel manipulation. And what I have noticed is that android does not kill programs or free memory in favor of the foreground app. And my app just crashes with not enough memory errors. Right now I have it autodetect how much memory is left and scale pictures appropriately. This prevents crashes but results in poor image quality.

Is there a way to tell Android OS, free up memory as my app is memory hungry. From what I read from android, the OS should do this automatically. But it doesn't appear to do it. Maybe I'm missing something? The iPhone seems as it handles this much better.

Answer (score 1):

Android apps have a hard Java heap limit which varies between devices. 24MB is a typical amount.

So the obvious workaround is to not allocate your big objects in Java... you can malloc your pixel byte arrays from a native C method instead.

However 24MB ought to be enough for anybody, to borrow a phrase, so I recommend you try to rethink your approach too. Perhaps be more aggressive about reusing bitmaps from a fixed-size pool, break your images up into smaller tiles, etc etc.

Comment: The big objects are just bitmaps. I already reuse the bitmaps as to prevent holes. Parsing /proc/meminfo seams to give the most reliable results in how much memory is on the device. From my testing so far I get out of memory errors when allocating a bitmap (haven't got memory errors for any other reason yet) and to me it seems to happen when the device itself is physically low on memory rather than java heap limit being reached as the graph of proc/meminfo goes close to 0.

Comment: Also when I kill apps, I could use more memory without any form of crashing. I'll try allocating everything natively and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `getPixel()` and `setPixel()` too much, it hence results in a really really bad performance, it's already mentioned on Android Documentation.
Also, manage your own memory usage Java, `Garbage Collector` will function as long as you follow the rule.